# Conditional component rendering react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

Im trying to render conditional component. I have MapView with the location, what i want to achieve is: If the location is granted from the user or the location can not be found, instead of MapView I want to render a Textinput where users can type their location manually. This is my code

```
export default class GpsLocation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: null,
    };
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
    });

    let region = {
      latitude: location.coords.latitude,
      longitude: location.coords.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0045,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0045,
    };
    this.setState({ region: region });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.status === "granted") {
      return (
        <View style={styles.locationContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.note}>Adresa</Text>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          showUserLocation={true}
          showCompass={true}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          style={{ flex: 1, borderRadius: 10 }}
        ></MapView>
      </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <TextInput/>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: null,
      status : undefined, // add initially `undefined`
    };
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

_getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    .......
    this.setState({ ... , status }); // update status here
  };

render() {
  // change here also
  return this.state.status === "granted" ? (
        <View style={styles.locationContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.note}>Adresa</Text>
          <MapView
            initialRegion={this.state.region}
            showUserLocation={true}
            showCompass={true}
            rotateEnabled={false}
            style={{ flex: 1, borderRadius: 10 }}
          ></MapView>
      </View>
      ) : <TextInput/> ;       
  }
```

Comment: this.status is not recognized and its not connecting to the  let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

Comment: Sorry i tested it and is not working this.status === "granted" should be something else because the status is not recognized, can u help me

Comment: Sill the same is only showing the TextInput, not the MapView when im giving permissions for location

Comment: Change `this.status` to `this.state.status` then try. I have updated also

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eMkbwBex  here is the code updated, but the same its not functional

Comment: Its working only its taking to long to find the location, the problem now is till it finds the location its showing the textinput. How to show a loader instead of textinput, becuase textinput should appear is the location is granted?